# Why does JSON.stringify() accept Date objects?

Tags: javascript, json, date

At least in Firefox, you can stringify a Date object:

```
>>> JSON.stringify({'now': new Date()})
'{"now":"2012-04-23T18:44:05.600Z"}'
```

This works because (in Firefox) `Date` contains a `toJSON` method which is used by its JSON serializer. However, this is not part of the JSON standard so I wonder why this method exists or rather why the builtin JSON serializer checks for such a method. Since it's not standardized you cannot safely use it anyway without first testing if the builtin serializer understands it and otherwise use a custom one (such as [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js))

Comment: It is part of the ECMAScript standard.

Comment: it also exists in Chrome: Date.prototype.toJSON

Comment: I thought it might be calling toString, but I tried that and you get a  different format of string.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Post it as a answer (e.g. with a quote from the ES standard) and I'll accept it. Just checked that document and it indeed defines how to serialize unknown objects.

Comment: If it is an ECMAScript standard, why isn't any standard for serializing Date object in JSON?

Comment: @KamyarNazeri — because it wasn't a data type that the JSON spec authors wanted to put into JSON. (Presumably on the principle of making JSON as simple as possible).

Comment: JSON is not intended to be a universal serialization format for JavaScript objects.  It uses JavaScript syntax, and therefore has JavaScript in the name, but it was designed to represent a subset of types that are found across a wide variety of languages: arrays and maps of strings, numbers, and booleans.  That's it.

Comment: @MarkReed: ISO8601 is a W3C standard format for Date: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime 
shouldn't be such standard for a serialization method used widely across the web?!

Comment: You should most certainly use ISO-8601 whenever converting a date to a string. At that point, however, what you are serializing *is* a string, not a Date object... and JSON supports strings just fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works because it is specified in a not so clear matter within the specification. Starting out you need to dig in into section **[15.12.3](http://es5.github.io/#x15.12.3)** in the description of the abstract operation **Str** which is used to convert values to a string representation. Essentially if the input is an object the specification says to check for the existance of a callable value named `toJSON`. Think of this like an interface in Java or C#.

```
interface IAmJSON 
{
    string toJSON(string key);
}
```

This is the exact text from the specification.

```
2.  If Type(value) is Object, then 
    a.  Let toJSON be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of  value with argument "toJSON". 
    b.  If IsCallable(toJSON) is true 
        i.  Let value be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of  toJSON passing value as the this value and with an argument list consisting of key.
```

Finally, the date object has `toJSON` defined in section **[15.9.5.44](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.44)**.